# Swiper Slide : Slideto clicking on outside slide

Tags: swiper.js

I have a Swiper slider with 3 slides per view (slides 1, 2 and 3). With CSS, through the overflow property, I've made the rest of the slides visible. I would need that when clicking on one of the slides that are outside the swiper slide (numbers 4, 5, 6 and subsequent) they could interact with the mouse events, to be able to move the active slide to which the click is made.

I can't get the sliders that are outside the swiper slider container to react to the mouse. I don't see any CSS properties that could interfere.

Thanks in advance.[image]

I've checked the CSS properties of the elements and the parent but I can't find why they don't respond to mouse interaction.